# class function inaccessible c++(beginner problem)

Tags: c++

Hello so i want to create a header file class which name testing and also its cpp but for some reason this is inaccessible i dont know why

testing.h

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class testing
{
    string Name;
    void printname(string name);
};

#endif
```

testing.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testing.h"

using namespace std;
void testing::printname(string name) // inaccessible in my main i dont know what reason :(
    {
        Name = name;
        cout<<Name<<endl;
    }
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testing.h"
using namespace std;
using std::string;
int main()
{

    testing tester;
    tester.printname("JPR"); //error since testing::printname is inaccessible no idea
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify the visibility of the members, they are private.

You can either use a struct (visibility is public):

```
struct testing
{
    string Name;
    void printname(string name);
};
```

or you can specify that `printname` is public:

```
class testing
{
  public:
    void printname(string name);

  private:
    string Name;
};
```

Try the following:

***testing.h***

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H

#include <string>

class testing
{
  public:
    // Better to pass the parameter as const reference to avoid performing a copy.
    void printname(const std::string& name);

  private:
    std::string Name;
};

#endif
```

***testing.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testing.h"

void testing::printname(const std::string& name)
{
    Name = name;
    std::cout << Name << std::endl;
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "testing.h"

int main()
{
    testing tester;
    tester.printname("JPR");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello but after i use the public and private i got this error 
In function 'int main()':
error: 'testing' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Can you post the whole source code? do you still have `#include "testing.h"` in `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

In C++:

> A class defined with the keyword class has private access for its members and its base classes by default.

Add `public:` access modifier to your class defition, to mark method as public:

```
class testing
{
    string Name;
public:
    void printname(string name);
};
```

Comment: Important: *as private access for its members **and its base classes*** remember the bolded bit for later.

Comment: thanks for the answer but after i did those i got this error 'int main()': error: 'testing' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Are you sure you didnt forget to include class definition this time in main()? Or added some namespace definition?
In the function (and file) where are you calling the method (main() in your case) the definition of class must be visible (which means it must happen before, often via #include, and within the right namespace).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a class, every member function and member variable is set in default as private, which means that they won't be accessible. To make your function public you need to change this in your code:

```
class testing
{
private: //is private in default, i add it for better readabilty
    string Name;
public:
    void printname(string name);
};
```

Worth to mention that you (almost) ALWAYS want to keep all member variables private!

Comment: thanks for the answer but after i did those i got this error 'int main()': error: 'testing' was not declared in this scope