# Why does vscode tell constructor defined outside class is inaccesible?

Tags: class, object, constructor

I have defined a constructor and then tried initializing an object but vscode tells me that the constructor is inaccessible. I don't understand what the problem is

this is my code

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
class player{
    // attributes
    int xp{0};
    string name;
    int health{0};
    float avg_score{0};
    int tot{0};
    int c{0};

    // methods
    void add_score(int score){
        tot += score;
        c++;
    };

    void display_avg_score(){
        avg_score = tot/c;
        cout << avg_score << endl;
    };

    void player_is_perfect(){
        if((xp > 5) && (avg_score > 23)){
            cout << "Perfect"<< endl;
        }
    };

    // defining a constructor
    player(int exp,float avg);
};

player::player(int exp,float avg){
    xp = exp;
    avg_score = avg;
};

int main(){
    player frank{23,45.6};
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class function inaccessible c++(beginner problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064519/class-function-inaccessible-cbeginner-problem)

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond specified, classes have default access specifier "private". Anything you want to access outside the class should be preceded by the "public" statement like so

```
class player{
  // attributes
  int xp{0};
  string name;
  int health{0};
  float avg_score{0};
  int tot{0};
  int c{0};

  public:
  // methods
  void add_score(int score){
      tot += score;
      c++;
  }

// rest of class
};
```